# Can't find Joomla pagination template

Tags: php, joomla, pagination

I'm going crazy with this one. I am trying to change a little bit the pagination style and layout in Joomla. So, I found this file: libraries\joomla\html\pagination.php but I know that pagination is overridden by this file: templates\gk_yourshop\html\pagination.php. Yet, if I modify something in gk_yourshop\html\pagination.php, I can't see the change in the pages. Does joomla cache templates and I have to re-load them (like phpBB)?. I don't understand.

I tried to check if writePagesLinks is called from joomla\html\pagination.php with this:

```
function getPagesLinks()
{
            echo "test";
    global $mainframe;
```

and I can't see the message. I also did this in the other pagination.php file and it's just like I can delete them and it doesn't matter. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: you need to locate file from which joomla renders that pagination. Put die() somewhere to see if you are in the right place and turn the cache off. When you find it you will be able to manipulate it the way it suits you

Comment: That's what I did. I'm sure that I have found the right pages. I'll try to turn the cache off.

Comment: You should edit the template, use `!important` if needed in your CSS files. Also go to General Settings > System > And set the cache off

Comment: Try **Ctrl + F5** which will force refresh the page.

Comment: I removed any code from both files and the pagination bar still appears.

Comment: I tested any pagination.php file from any template, no one works. It must be the cache. The CSS changes works, only the HTML doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you getting WritePageLinks from? That's not one of the supported methods.

http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Pagination_Links_Overrides

There are four functions that can be used:

> pagination_list_footer
>
> This function is responsible for showing the select list for the
>   number of items to display per page.
>
> pagination_list_render
>
> This function is responsible for showing the list of page number links
>   as well at the Start, End, Previous and Next links.
>
> pagination_item_active
>
> This function displays the links to other page numbers other than the
>   "current" page.
>
> pagination_item_inactive
>
> This function displays the current page number, usually not
>   hyperlinked.
>
> [edit]

You may also want to look at Protostar as an example.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like I changed it here some time ago:
`\libraries\joomla\html\pagination.php`

But, that is system file, so i just make a "hotfix" of it.

Comment: and if site is not live try to catch changes not by `echo`, but with `die`.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla 3.x you can create pagination override from Extensions > Templates > Default Template > Create Overrides > Layouts > Pagination.

The override files are created in "Default Template" "html\layouts\joomla\pagination" folder.

You can edit the override files as per your needs.